InfoWindow not closing after navigating to others routes
I'm trying to manage the click event in google map so any click on map it will close the unique infoWindow variable, so I'll share the portions of code that are related with this issue in my mapView.vue component I have this lifecycle hook:
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary('marker')) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary

  usingMapStore.unableMap = 'cargandoMapa'
  usingMapStore.isLoading = true

  const variables = await loadVariables(props.tipoMapa) as MapProps

  map.value = await initMap(props.tipoMapa)
  checkLayoutHeight()

  infowindow.value = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ disableAutoPan: true, maxWidth: 120, minWidth: 80 })
  mapProps.value = variables as MapProps
  markerClusterC = new MarkerClusterer({ algorithm, renderer })
  markerClusterC.setMap(map.value)

  mapClickRef.value = map.value?.addListener('click', () => {
    limpiaMapa(infowindow.value as google.maps.InfoWindow, props.tipoMapa)
  })

  try {
    if (usingMapStore.allMarkers.length === 0) {
      await initMarcadores()
      mapProps.value.assignCustomLocs!(usingMapStore.allMarkers)
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing markers:', error)
  }

  try {
    await nextTick()
    await waitForDOMElements()
    await initializeObserver()
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing observer:', error)
  }

  try {
    await getUserGeolocation()
  }
  catch (geoError) {
    console.error('Error fetching user geolocation:', geoError)
  }

  await nextTick()
  idleRef.value = map.value?.addListener('idle', () => {
    usingMapStore.unableMap = ''
  })
  usingMapStore.isLoading = false
  usingMapStore.setCenterGeolocation(map.value as google.maps.Map)
})

then after navigating to any other route of the app and going back, infowindow variable opens well on every marker click but not closes making reference to the same variable and not thowing anything on console. In any case I remove event listeners onUnMounted hook like this:
 onUnmounted(() => {
  emptyMap(markerClusterC)
  limpiaMapa(infowindow.value!, props.tipoMapa)

  if (map.value) {
    google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(map.value)
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map.value, 'click')
  }

  if (mapClickRef.value) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(mapClickRef.value)
    mapClickRef.value = null
  }

  if (idleRef.value) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(idleRef.value)
    idleRef.value = null
  }

  observerMapContainer.value?.disconnect()
  usingRoutePassing.assignItems(null)
  mapProps.value = undefined
  infowindow.value = undefined
})

So the close directive comes when limpiaMapa() is called and it's looks like this:
export async function limpiaMapa(infowindow: google.maps.InfoWindow, tipoMapa: string) {
  const { mapStateProps } = await loadVariables(tipoMapa) as MapProps

  mapStateProps.infoFichaHelper = null
  infowindow.close()
}

Any suggestions on how to make infoWindow variable close itself when the event map click it's fired even if user change route?

Are you able to provide a simple codepen/sandbox so the community can check?
